# If $f$ is bounded, show that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=f(0).$

Tags: real-analysis

> Question: Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function satisfying $f(2x)=3f(x)$ for every $0\le x\le 1/2.$ If $f$ is bounded, show that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=f(0).$

My approach: It is given that $f(2x)=3f(x)$ for every $0\le x\le 1/2.$ Note that this is equivalent to stating that $f(x)=3f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right), \forall x\in [0,1].$ Let this condition be denoted by $(*)$. Setting $x=0$ in $(*)$ we have $f(0)=0$. Thus, we need to show that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=0.$

Now select any $x\in[0,1]$. Note that from $(*)$ we can conclude that $$f\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)=\frac{1}{3^n}f(x), \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$$ Thus, since $\left(\frac{1}{3^n}\right)_{n\ge 1}$ converges to $0$ and $(f(x))_{n\ge 1}$ converges to $f(x)$, implies that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)=0.$$ Thus, for all $x\in[0,1]$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)=0$.

My aim is to show that for any sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge 1}$ converging to $0$, the sequence $(f(x_n))_{n\ge 1}$ converges to $0$. And since it is given that $f$ is bounded, so it seems to me that we can somehow use Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem to prove the same. Can someone help me proceed?

---

P.S.: Solution: Note that from $(*)$ we can conclude that $$f\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)=\frac{1}{3^n}f(x), \forall x\in [0,1] \text{ and }\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$$ Let this relation be denoted by $(**)$.

Now since it is given that $f$ is bounded, so let us assume that for all $x\in[0,1]$ we have, $|f(x)|<M$ for some $M>0$.

Next select any $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and any $x$ satisfying $0<x<\frac{1}{2^m},$ and let $y:=2^m x$. Note that $y\in(0,1)$. Setting $x=y$ and $n=m$ in $(**),$ we have $$f(x)=\frac{1}{3^m}f(y)\implies |f(x)|=\frac{1}{3^m}|f(y)|\le \frac{M}{3^m}.$$

Thus, for any $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and any $x$ satisfying $0<x<\frac{1}{2^m},$ we have $$\frac{1}{3^m}|f(y)|\le \frac{M}{3^m}\hspace{0.2 cm}(***).$$

Now select any $\epsilon>0$ and let $\delta=\frac{1}{2^n},$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is large enough to satisfy $3^n>\frac{M}{\epsilon}$. So, for any $0<x<\delta=\frac{1}{2^n},$ from $(***)$ we have  $$|f(x)-0|=|f(x)|\le \frac{M}{3^n}<\epsilon.$$ This implies that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=0$ and hence we are done.

Comment: I would maybe prefer to go contrapositive: Assume the limit doesn't exist, then show that the function cannot possibly be bounded, using the same functional equation.

Comment: Could someone explain how OP deduced that $f\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)=\frac{1}{3^n}f(x)$ from $(*)$? Either I've got a bit of reading to do or my brain simply isn't working right now.

Comment: @A.E.Rosas Take $f(x)=3f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$, divide by $3$, then apply repeatedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you just need to find $\delta_\epsilon>0$ such that if $\delta_\epsilon> x>0$, then $\vert f(x)\vert<\epsilon$. Since $\vert f(x)\vert \leq M$, you just have to notice that if $\frac{1}{2^n}>x>0$, then there exists $y\in (0,1]$ such that $x=\frac{y}{2^n}$. Then by what you wrote:
$$ \vert f(x)\vert = \frac{1}{3^n} \vert f(y)\vert\leq \frac{M}{3^n}, $$

and you can find an appropriate $\delta_\epsilon$ by that relation. I don't think it would be simpler to then show with sequences, but rather just work with the definition of a one sided limit.

Comment: Thanks, this worked out really well. I have added the solution to the original post. Check if it looks good to you or not.

Comment: @SanketBiswas It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Take an arbitrary $x$ in the specified range. We know that $f(x)$ is bounded, say by $M$.

Then for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $k$ such that $$\forall x:0\le x\le\frac12:f(2^{-k}x)=3^{-k}f(x)\le 3^{-k}M\le\epsilon.$$

So $\forall\epsilon:\exists \delta=2^{-k}x$ that ensures the convergence condition.